# How to change memory of dll process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cheat-engine

when i try to change the memory nothing happens because its targeting the wrong thing, i'm not sure how to get the specific process of aj classic and how to target "pepflashplayer.dll" when changing memory

the pointer is for "pepflashplayer.dll", got the pointer via cheat engine, does not work if you choose the aj classic application, you have to go into processes and try them until you get the 1 specific process where it works, i'm new to this so i'm writing it in python since its simple and easy

i tried:

```
rwm = ReadWriteMemory()
self.process = rwm.get_process_by_name('AJ Classic.exe')
```

which did not change the memory how i wanted it to. this question may be very dumb but   ¯\_(ツ)__/¯